# Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty} |\sin x^2|\,dx$ doesn't converge.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $I=\int_{0}^{\infty} |\sin x^2|\,dx$ doesn't converge. It is easy to see that $I=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_n$, where $a_n=\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}} |\sin x^2|\,dx>\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}-\sqrt{n\pi}}{2}=b_n$(the area of the triangle with base=$(\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}-\sqrt{n\pi})$ and $h=1$.

Then $\sum a_n > \sum b_n$, but $\sum b_n$ converges, so I don't get any conclusion. Does anyone have other idea? Thank you.

Comment: $b_n$ may converge, but its sum exceeds sqrt(n+1) in the long run. Which doesn't converge.

Comment: Hello, Pieter. I think that $\sum b_n$ diverges because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{|b_n|}<1$

Comment: @Walterr: Please concentrate. You just claimed that the sum _diverges_ because the n-th root of bn is less than 1. One, "the sum diverges" is the opposite of "the sum converges" which you claimed in your question. Two, if the limit of the n-th root of bn were less than 1, the sum would converge. Third, the limit of the n-th root of bn is equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea that you asked for: Re-evaluate your opinion that the sum of bn converges. Trivially, bn is roughly some constant divided by the square root of n. And adding bn from 1 to N is roughly some constant times the square root of N.

Instead of integrating |$\sin x^2$|, integrate the constant 1. Subdivide the interval [0, inf] in exactly the same way as you did. Each sub-integral is equal to $2 b_n$ instead of $b_n$. That should make it obvious that your idea that the sum of $b_n$ converges cannot be right.

Answer (score 2):

For any $k\in\mathbb{N}^*$ we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi k}}|\sin x^2|\,dx &=& \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi k}\frac{|\sin x|}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\\ &=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin x|\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\pi}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+(k-1)\pi}}\right)\,dx\\&\geq&\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{kx}{\sqrt{x+(k-1)\pi}}\,dx\geq\frac{k}{\pi\sqrt{(k-1/2)\pi}}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{8}\\&\geq&\frac{\sqrt{(k-1/2)\pi}}{8},\end{eqnarray*}$$
ensuring divergence.

Comment: It would be an awful lot easier to fix the tiny flaw in the OP's otherwise correct proof.

Comment: @gnasher729 I feel like this is a cleaner proof in case OP's goal was just to prove its divergence, and not to prove it using any particular method.